# Search 2 columns for parts of string in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to search inside 2 columns for parts of a string.  It's a backwards way of searching so I doubt it's possible.

I think part of it would have something to do with:

```
REPLACE( event_name, ' ', '')
```

and

```
REPLACE( venue_name, ' ', '')
```

to get rid of the space.

I also thought REGEX might come into it.

Absolutely no idea where to start! PSUEDOCODE might be:

```
CONCAT(
event_name = REPLACE( part of :search, ' ', '')
,
venue_name = REPLACE( part of :search, ' ', '')
)
= :search
```

If I used `noddybobstheatre` as the search term I want to search the column event_name for part of it and venue_name for another part and when the 2 parts are put together they equal the search term.

```
event_name = 'noddy'
venue_name = 'bobs theatre'
```

Like I said, this might be a crazy ask...

Comment: Why does not the search string have spaces?

Comment: Because the search comes from the URL like domain.com/searchstringtext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading what you need I thought that the like statement should use the column and not the search value.

here is my reproduction of what I understood from your problem

```
CREATE TABLE movies
    (`word1` varchar(5), `word2` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO movies
    (`word1`, `word2`)
VALUES
    ('micko', 'to'),
    ('he', 'llbrane'),
    ('mick', 'oto'),
    ('hell', 'brane')
;
```

then here is the sql statement that I used

```
select * from movies where 'mickoto' like CONCAT(Replace(word1,' ',''),'%') and 'mickoto' like CONCAT('%',Replace(word2,' ',''))
```

all you have is to adapt this to your context

[here is the fiddle execution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f05ecf/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

use this,

`concat(replace(event_name,' ',''),replace(venue_name,' ',''), )=:search`